# extracting a text with awk

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I want to grep a file and extract the third part of this line

```
#define SIM_VERSION_COMPAT 1302
```

with awk. So I wrote:

```
grep "#define SIM_VERSION_COMPAT" global.h | awk '{ print $$3 }'
```

The result should be 1302 but I get nothing (blank).

Comment: Remove extra $ from awk syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[spatel@tc01 ~]$ echo "#define SIM_VERSION_COMPAT 1302" | awk '{ print $3 }'
1302
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to use grep and pipe you can use awk like this:

```
awk '/#define SIM_VERSION_COMPAT/{print $3}' global.h
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using `grep`:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=#define SIM_VERSION_COMPAT )[0-9]+' global.h
1302
```

This uses [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match lines containing `#define SIM_VERSION_COMPAT` but only prints the digit string following.

Comment: @olibre my bad I assumed you was the OP without checking `:|` good to know my answer is helpful to others also.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cut command as well

```
grep "#define SIM_VERSION_COMPAT" temp.txt | cut -d" " -f 3
```